# TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement

Tags: javascript, canvas, ecmascript-6, drawimage

Following the turorial with the same exact code, but getting this error to a console when trying to draw an image to a canvas:

> SpriteSheet.js:30 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)

No idea why is this happening? The first image is drawed fine on the canvas but the second one is not showing up and getting this error. Using promises so all the images should be loaded before using them, right? It works fine if I change the end of the script.js file to `drawBackground(level.backgrounds[1], context, sprites);`

**script.js**

```
import SpriteSheet from './SpriteSheet.js';
import {loadImage, loadLevel} from './loaders.js';

function drawBackground(background, context, sprites) {
    background.ranges.forEach(([x1, x2, y1, y2]) => {
        for (let x = x1; x < x2; ++x) {
            for (let y = y1; y < y2; ++y) {
                sprites.drawTile(background.tile, context, x, y);
            }
        }
    });
}

function loadBackgroundSprites() {
  return loadImage('SEA01.png').then(image => {
    const sprites = new SpriteSheet(image, 16, 16);
    sprites.define('ocean', 0, 0);
    return sprites;
});
  return loadImage('ground.png').then(image=> {
    const sprites = new SpriteSheet(image, 16, 16);
    sprites.define('ground', 12, 0);
  });
}

const canvas = document.getElementById('gamearea');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

Promise.all([
  loadBackgroundSprites(),
  loadLevel('1-1')
]).then(([sprites,level]) => {
  console.log(level);
  drawBackground(level.backgrounds[0], context, sprites);
});
```

**loader.js**

```
export function loadImage(url) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const image = new Image();
        image.addEventListener('load', () => {
            resolve(image);
        });
        image.src = url;
    });
}

export function loadLevel(name) {
    return fetch(`/levels/${name}.json`)
    .then(r => r.json());
}
```

**spritesheet.js**

```
export default class SpriteSheet {
    constructor(image, w = 16, h = 16) {
        this.image = image;
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
        this.tiles = new Map();
    }

    define(name, x, y) {
        const buffer = document.createElement('canvas');
        buffer.height = this.height;
        buffer.width = this.width;
        buffer
            .getContext('2d')
            .drawImage(
                this.image,
                this.width * x,
                this.height * y,
                this.width,
                this.height,
                0,
                0,
                this.width,
                this.height);
        this.tiles.set(name, buffer);
    }

    draw(name, context, x, y) {
        const buffer = this.tiles.get(name);
        context.drawImage(buffer, x, y);
    }

    drawTile(name, context, x, y) {
        this.draw(name, context, x * this.width, y * this.height);
    }
}
```

**1-1.json**

```
{
    "backgrounds": [
        {
            "tile": "ocean",
            "ranges": [
                [
                    0, 50,
                    0, 25
                ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "tile": "ground",
            "ranges": [
                [
                    18, 25,
                    10, 15
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I updated my code to load the images in different functions, but get the same error:

script.js

```
import SpriteSheet from './SpriteSheet.js';
import {loadImage, loadLevel} from './loaders.js';

const canvas = document.getElementById('gamearea');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

function drawBackground(background, context, sprites) {
    background.ranges.forEach(([x1, x2, y1, y2]) => {
        for (let x = x1; x < x2; ++x) {
            for (let y = y1; y < y2; ++y) {
                sprites.drawTile(background.tile, context, x, y);
            }
        }
    });
}

function drawMario(background, context, mario) {
    background.ranges.forEach(([x1, x2, y1, y2]) => {
        for (let x = x1; x < x2; ++x) {
            for (let y = y1; y < y2; ++y) {
                mario.drawTile(background.tile, context, x, y);
            }
        }
    });
}

function loadBackgroundSprites() {
  return loadImage('SEA01.png').then(image => {
    const sprites = new SpriteSheet(image, 16, 16);
    sprites.define('ocean', 0, 0);
    return sprites;
  });
}

function loadDirtSprite() {
  return loadImage('ground.png').then(image => {
    const mario = new SpriteSheet(image, 16, 16);
    mario.define('ground', 12, 0);
    return mario;
  });
}



Promise.all([
  loadBackgroundSprites(),
  loadLevel('1-1'),
  loadDirtSprite()
]).then(([sprites, level, mario]) => {
  level.backgrounds.forEach(background => {
    drawBackground(background, context, sprites, mario);
  });
  mario.draw('ground', context, 1, 16);
});
```

Comment: `function loadBackgroundSprites`  has two return statements with the second one generating an "unreachable code" _warning_ (the code to load and create a 'ground' sprite  doesn't execute). Is this related to the problem? Do you get any other console errors?

Comment: It is definitely related to what @traktor53 mentioned: `this.tiles.get('ground')` will return undefined because `loadImage('ground.png')` will never get called.

Comment: @traktor53 it's not related at all, because if I put them in a different function and call from my promise I still get the same error. And no, no more errors, only this one. I updated my OP with different code but same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*replaced answer:*

**Bug number 1.**

Mentioned in question comment, the original code has an error in `loadBackgroundSprites`:

```
function loadBackgroundSprites() {
  return loadImage('SEA01.png').then(image => {
    const sprites = new SpriteSheet(image, 16, 16);
    sprites.define('ocean', 0, 0);
    return sprites;
});                                  // <-- bad indent
  return loadImage('ground.png').then(image=> {
    const sprites = new SpriteSheet(image, 16, 16);
    sprites.define('ground', 12, 0);
  });
}
```

The line in the middle marked as "bad indent" is where the return statement started at the beginning of `loadBackgroundSprites` ends and execution returns to the caller. The `return` statement after the "bad indent" line never executes and  generates a console message.

> ⚠  unreachable code after return statement [[Learn More]](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Stmt_after_return)

Because the warning is non-fatal, the function returns without error.

The first fix for this bug is to remove the unreachable code. Two additional fixes are required as discussed under the next bug.

- change the URL loaded to that of a sprite sheet file (still to be prepared),
- define both an "ocean" and "ground" tile in the promise handler for `loadImage`

**Bug number 2.**

Instances of the `SpriteSheet`class contain a single image, passed as the argument to the constructor. This image should contain an array of rectangular tiles of fixed width and height matching the 2nd and 3rd parameter values used in the constructor call. This is not what you are doing.

Actually, defining a tile in a `SpriteSheet` instance copies a single tile from the sprite sheet image into a new, named Canvas object for use by drawing functions.

A suggested remedy for working with sprite sheets as designed is to create a backgrounds sprite sheet image that contains at least the two 16x16 tiles for ocean and ground. Their positions in the sprite sheet image (counting tiles left-across and top-down) determines how tile definition should be coded in `loadBackgroundSprites`.

For this solution, remove code references to `dirtSprite`. And remove image references to "SEA01.png" and "ground.png" - `loadBackgroundSprites` should be loading the URL for a combined sprite sheet containing both tiles.

In the `Promise.all` chain use use the `forEach` version of the code to render the sprites according to the json file:

```
Promise.all([
  loadBackgroundSprites(),
  loadLevel('1-1')
]).then(([sprites,level]) => {
  console.log(level);
  level.backgrounds.forEach(background => {
    drawBackground(background, context, sprites)
  });
```

---

I hope that helps with the tutorial.

Comment: But how can I make sprites object contain a tile for `ground`? Both functions `loadDirtSprite()` defines ground for sprites object. How come its not working then?

Comment: I updated my OP with code refactor again. Same error.. I feel like giving up.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FF93S8rLL_Q&t=350s 6:00 - 8:25 it works fine for a guy even with my old code :?

Comment: Oh okay, I figured it out. Looks like my loop doesn't loop through second 'ground' element in JSON. Still trying to figure it out why, but if I hardcode it directly without using JSON, it works fine.

Comment: You have not understood my answer at all. I'll see if I can improve it over the weekend.

Comment: Thanks, that would really help!

Comment: I've replacement the answer. There's an issue with sprite sheets that I only discovered today anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

I know this was quite some time ago. But when you created a new promise in the loader.js module - Make sure to add a .catch((err) => console.log(err))

Also after you update if you're still seeing the problem trying Ctrl+Shift+R to refresh the static http cache which may still be caching your old code. If this helps, let me know!

**loader.js**

```
export function loadImage(url) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const image = new Image();
        image.addEventListener('load', () => {
            resolve(image);
        });
        image.src = url;
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err)); <--------ADD THIS
}
```